# Comma at the end of last BibTeX field

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

A BibTeX entry looks like

```
@entry_type{internal_key,
  field_1 = "value_1",
  field_2 = "value_2",
  ...
  field_n = "value_n"
}
```

I've seen examples that put a comma after `"value_n"`. Is there any difference between putting a comma and not putting it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is just to be safe. If you later want to add a new field entry in your `bib` file it happens very often that you forgot to add the missing comma in the field before.

```
@entry_type{internal_key,
  field_1 = "value_1",
  field_2 = "value_2",
  ...
  field_n = "value_n"
  new_field = "newValue"
}
```

So with the added `new_field` you will have compiling errors because the comma after `field_n` is missing. If you always write the comma this error can't happen:

Write always

```
@entry_type{internal_key,
  field_1 = "value_1",
  field_2 = "value_2",
  ...
  field_n = "value_n",
}
```

to avoid this error.

A good hint comes from krlmlr in his comment: "Also, this makes a subtle difference when you use version control for the `.bib` file: If a comma terminates the last field, you do not have to touch this line to add another field, and it's easier to track the origin of this line (e.g., with `svn annotate`)."

And tohecz comments: "As well, the auto-generation is simpler then. It's the same reason as why you can have comma after list array item in C++."

Comment: Also, this makes a subtle difference when you use version control for the `.bib` file: If a comma terminates the last field, you do not have to touch this line to add another field, and it's easier to track the origin of this line (e.g., with `svn annotate`).

Comment: As well, the auto-generation is simpler then. It's the same reason as why you can have comma after list array item in `C++`.